# Query to return subgraph and all internal relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, networkx, graph-theory

Given the following graph:

[image]

Which is creatable by the following Cypher script:

```
CREATE
    (n1:Token {content: "lonely"}),
    (n2:Token {content: "island"}),
    (n1)-[:PRECEDES]->(n2);


CREATE
    (n1:Token {content: "the"}),
    (n2:Token {content: "quick"}),
    (n3:Token {content: "brown"}),
    (n4:Token {content: "fox"}),
    (n5:Token {content: "bear"}),
    (n1)-[:PRECEDES]->(n2),
    (n2)-[:PRECEDES]->(n3),
    (n3)-[:PRECEDES]->(n4),
    (n3)-[:PRECEDES]->(n5);
```

I want a query that will return nodes in the path from a given root, following
the PRECEDES relationships backwards.  The query should *also* return all
incoming relationships for the given node, so that I can construct the subgraph
in-memory later.  However, the list of incoming relationships should never point
outside of the returned root.

For instance, if I query for the root `lonely`, I want the result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (:Token {content: "lonely"}) | []                                     |
| (:Token {content: "island"}) | [[:PRECEDES]]                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I query for the root `the`, I want the result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (:Token {content: "the"})   | []                                      |
| (:Token {content: "quick"}) | [[:PRECEDES]]                           |
| (:Token {content: "brown"}) | [[:PRECEDES]]                           |
| (:Token {content: "fox"})   | [[:PRECEDES]]                           |
| (:Token {content: "bear"})  | [[:PRECEDES]]                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I query for the root `brown`, I want the following result, note that the
incoming relationship for `brown` itself has been elided because it would
point outside of the subgraph.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (:Token {content: "brown"}) | []                                      |
| (:Token {content: "fox"})   | [[:PRECEDES]]                           |
| (:Token {content: "bear"})  | [[:PRECEDES]]                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The root and leaf nodes should always be included in the result.

This is my attempt so far:

```
MATCH (a:Token {content: {root}})-[:PRECEDES*]->(t:Token)
WITH COLLECT(a) + COLLECT(DISTINCT t) AS nodes_
UNWIND nodes_ AS n
OPTIONAL MATCH p = (n)-[r]-()
WITH n AS n2, COLLECT(DISTINCT RELATIONSHIPS(p)) AS nestedrel
RETURN n2, REDUCE(output = [], rel in nestedrel | output + rel) AS rels
```

This is sort-of close but has several problems: the use of `COLLECT(a)` to
artificially include the root is kind of hacky, it leaves relationships that
point away from the root in the relationship result, and if you try to use a
leaf node as the root it won't return any nodes at all.  (The `REDUCE` part is
just flattening the relationship list by one level.)

[FYI the application is I need to rebuild this tree structure in memory as a
NetworkX MultiDiGraph.]

Comment: Hi @amoe, since you are trying to reconstruct the subgraph in memory later, have you tried using the [APOC Procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_overview_of_apoc_procedures_functions) `apoc.convert.toTree`?

Comment: For example: you can run queries like match p = (:Token {content: "the"})-[:PRECEDES*]->(end:Token) where not (end)-[:PRECEDES]->() call apoc.convert.toTree([p]) yield value return value This way you can get a tree structure, without need of transformations.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the tip -- I'll investigate this!

Comment: Right! If it works, then I will answer your question with this solution! :)

Comment: This has indeed worked for me, because I can use networkx's `tree_graph` to read in the paths that `apoc.convert.toTree` creates, and merge the in-memory trees together using `networkx.compose`.

Comment: I'm still slightly curious, academically speaking, if there actually is a plain Cypher query that will work as specced in the question, but this solves my problem.

Comment: Hi @amoe. I answered your question with my solution. Unfortunately I don't know about a plain Cypher that solve your question, but I think it does not exists at a first glance. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to reconstruct the subgraph in memory later, you can use the [APOC procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `apoc.convert.toTree` and return a tree structure directly, without the need of transformations. So you can run queries like:

```
match p = (:Token {content: "the"})-[:PRECEDES*]->(end:Token)
where not (end)-[:PRECEDES]->()
call apoc.convert.toTree([p]) yield value
return value
```